# My function key broke – how can I send a key event to Windows 7 to change brightness?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts

My function key on my laptop broke, and I can't dim the screen, its killing my eyes.  How can I send a Function Key + F5 to the OS?

Its a Sony.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the mobility center in Windows 7 using `Windows Key + X` then adjust the screen brightness.

[image: Windows 7 Mobility center]

Comment: Display brightness doesn't show up for me (Volume is the first item) but this gave me something much better - under "Dell" there is access to the function key behavoir, to turn off the media key first feature that seem to get enabled in the BIOS from time to time for no reason.

Comment: @David many OEMs customize this mobility center with their own stuff (My previous HP laptop had custom features specific to the hardware on that laptop)

Comment: The hotkey didn't work, but it was in control panel

Comment: still this solution requires mouse...I would be happy if der is an alternate key combination for the purpose.

Answer (score 1):

A different approach to the problem is to change the keymap in registry.

If u want to do that through an app, you can try [*SharpKeys from RandyRants.com*](http://www.randyrants.com/sharpkeys). I am a happy user of this tiny freeware.

Here is my snapshot:
[image]